# jQuery toggle menu click through problems

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle

I'm just trying to create a simple toggle menu with jQuery but can't quite get it working.

In it's current state it doesn't slide toggle

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="one.html">One</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="one-one.html">one one</a></li>
            <li><a href="one-two.html">one two</a></li>
            <li><a href="one-three.html">one three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="two.html">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="three.html">Three</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="three-one.html">three one</a></li>
            <li><a href="three-two.html">three two</a></li>
            <li><a href="three-three.html">three three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="four.html">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Hide the sub menu items first
    $("ul#menu > li > ul").hide();

    // On click
    $('ul#menu > li').click(function() {

        // If there are sub items toggle them & prevent default click action
        if ( ('ul#menu > li').has('ul').length > 0 ) {
            $('ul#menu > li > ul').slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
        };

    });
});
```

I need it to slide toggle but also handle the clicks appropriately so the parent list items don't click through but the sub menu items do click through to their relevant pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want if I understand your question correctly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Hide the sub menu items first
    $("ul#menu > li > ul").hide();

    // On click
    $('ul#menu > li > a').click(function() {
        if($('ul', $(this).parent()).children().length) {
            $('ul', $(this).parent()).slideToggle("slow"); 
            return false; 
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    $('ul#menu > li').click(function(e) {
        // If there are sub items toggle them & prevent default click action
        if ($(e.target).is("li")) { 
            // or (e.target == this) if you don't want child li's to toggle
            $('ul', this).slideToggle("slow");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    });
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/5fNbh/

Update: takes care of additional cases you specified in comments.

Comment: I gave this a test both locally and with JSFiddle but it didn't seem to work. Clicking on each menu item just goes straight through to that page with no slide toggle(?)

Comment: Ian: I assumed that's what you wanted since your anchor tags had specific targets (one.html, etc..). I modified my answer so that clicking on the top level anchors will not follow their targets.

Comment: Sorry about that. I should have specified. I'm just mimicking the action of the CMS output I plan to use it with which links the parents even though they don't need to go anywhere if they have children. There is still one slight issue though in that list items which DON'T have children also have their links deactivated. Is there a way to check to see if a list item has children and if not then keep the link? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to fix it! Sorry for my ignorance though but I'm just trying to figure out why the second click handler is needed and why specifically it is placed on the li instead of the li a as the one above? Is it not possible to simply say if it has a sub menu then toggle and prevent click but if no sub menu is present follow the link? Obviously it works but I'm just looking to understand exactly why and what it's doing. Thanks again.

Comment: Ian: second click handler for LI is so that the users can optionally click on LI elements, which will have larger area than anchor elements, to expand/close menu items. I figured it was important in your design because you're binding click event handler to LIs in your question.

Comment: Ah thanks. Useful to know and well observed :). Is the function(e) just so you can more readily identify it in the code or is it to prevent any kind of inheritance in the script? So essentially both handlers do the same thing but cater for both the li and li a to be clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The

```
return false;
```

adds e.preventDefault() (and stop propagation) to the <li> instead of the <a> tag.
 rebind the click to the <a> or do

```
$('#menu')
  .find('li').has('ul')
  .find('a').click(function() { return false; });
```

(see the <a> is now getting the return false?)

Comment: Ah good point. I've changed it to the following: $('ul#menu > li > a').click(function() {

Answer (score 0):

This has been done a number of times. Check these links out:

- http://www.zlwo.com/plugins/15-best-multi-level-menu-jquery-plugins-and-tutorials/
- http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/
- http://www.narga.net/sexy-jquery-drop-down-multi-level-menu/

Comment: Thanks for the links but I'm not looking for plugins or fancy effect menu's. I just want to understand why it isn't working and build on the basics from there. For me it's more important to understand why than to use a plugin that would do it for me.